# Customizing HTTPstatus code

Tags: iis-6

I am using IIS6.0. Is there any way to customize the HTTPstatus code in HTTP header which we receive in response. My Requirement is to issue a 404- not found command in place of 403-Forbidden for a specific folder access(say images). So i need to customize Status code not custom error message.

thanks-
abhishek

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the IIS Manager and goto the web app in question
2. Right-click on the folder whose 403 behavior you want to modify and select "properties"
3. Select the "Customer Errors" tab
4. Change the file/behavior specified the 403 behavior you want to modify

This change will apply to the folder in question as well as sub-folders, so if you don't want this setting to cascade then you'll need to undo what you just did for sub-folders.

Comment: Then map the specific 403 behavior to a script which emits a page with the headers you want.